# Block level using LRU method

Tags: c++, c

Iam having the following problem.

I am working on a project and i need to use some libraries that i have not access in this code. In those libraries there is a function Read(int,int,void**).
Third parameter is to return a pointer to a block so i can gain access. However, after many Reads and because of LRU method in the block level, when i have stored in variable void* block a pointer to a block, i loose access in it at some point.

I tried to make a :

```
char temp[BLOCK_SIZE];
memcpy(temp,block,BLOCK_SIZE);
```

after the Reads i know i will loose and then use only temp instead of block but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas for solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What does the block contain? It may be that you need to do a deep copy instead of a shallow one. And what does "doesn't work" mean? Please provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Block is initialized with zeros. But i can save strings/ints/chars in it. 
About problem, i mean i loose the correct info at last.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that maximum memory allocated to block will be BLOCK_SIZE? It will be good if you can share the code snippet where you are calling the Read function

Comment: Iam not sure if that would really help you.

First of all yes iam sure about that, it's defined :
#defined BLOCK_SIZE 512

The call of the function is :

ReadBlock((int)fileDesc,(int)block_no,(void*)&block)

First parameter is the id of the open file which file include blocks.
Second parameters is the number of block to read.
And the third parameter is a pointer to the block.